# how can i break line in text container

Tags: jquery

how to break line in this code:

```
if (imageTextContainer.length > 0) {
    imageTextContainer.text(imageItem.text +imageItem.dec);
}
```

How to get this result:

```
imageItem.text </br> imageItem.dec
```

I have this code::

```
{
    image : "<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/pictures/1.jpg", 
    alt : "Picture 1",
    dec : "rockstar games",
    text : "Grand Theft Auto San Andres\r\n"
}
```

`\r\n` it's not work only echo space

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYd26.png) toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: Sorry my English is BAD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (imageTextContainer.length > 0) {
     imageTextContainer.html(imageItem.text + '<br>' + imageItem.dec);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  if (imageTextContainer.length > 0) {
     imageTextContainer.html(imageItem.text + "<br />" +imageItem.dec);
  }
```